# How do I use a checkbox to toggle another element?

Tags: jquery

How can I check if my checkbox with an `id` of `UseUsername` has been checked, and then use that information to toggle another element with an `id` of `div`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's as easy as:

```
$('#UseUsername').change(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    $('#div').show();
  } else {
    $('#div').hide();
  }
});
```

Additionally, you could fire this event when the page loads, so the div will disappear if the checkbox isn't checked.

```
// Show the div only if the checkbox is checked
function toggleDiv(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    $('#div').show();
  } else {
    $('#div').hide();
  }
}

$(document).onload(function(){

  // Set change event to hide/show the div
  $('#UseUsername')
    .change(toggleDiv)
    .trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: i use display: none so the div dont appears

Comment: +1 for being able to understand the original question XD

Comment: on unchecked -> else part is not working     $('#sampathcrdr').change(function(){
if($(this).is(':checked')){
alert("ok");
 } else {
alert("Gonee");
  }
});

Answer (score 13):

A very simple way would be like this:

```
$('#UseUsername').change(function(){
    $('#div').toggle(this.checked);  // show if it is checked, otherwise hide
});
```

**Try it:** http://jsfiddle.net/mHNuN/

Comment: This solution is much better than mine :]

Comment: I think Harmen's solution is better. Using toggle can lead to the checkbox state and the desired functionality becoming out of sync. Best to test the state after each change.

Comment: Using the (bool) overload of toggle should not cause the page to become out of sync, as you pass in if it has to be shown or note