# Text Toggle in HTML by jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $("input").click(function(){
             $("p").toggle(500);
           });
        });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="ON"/>  Secure E-mail
        </label>

        <p>This is another small paragraph.</p>
    </body>

</html>
```

Here The text i want to toggle is already be shown.

My requirement is, Only When I check the Checkbox , the Text Should appear.
Otherwise it should remain hidden
Help!

-Thank you

Comment: You can also use http://jsfiddle.net/ to share code

Comment: Try [this.......](http://jsfiddle.net/mqb93/)

Comment: duplicate from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642993/jquery-on-checked-toggle-box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the default display of the element to none: `p{display:none;}`

Also make sure to only toggle the single element you need, instead of all `<p>` elements

Code example here: http://jsfiddle.net/JXpg4/

Comment: I would change accepted answer for one of @Arun P Johny. It's a lot better because of form remembering by browsers (so it will be working in wrong way, invisible on checked).

Comment: Also @Jervelund you have special place for javascript on js fiddle and you can use library and document ready from dropdownboxes.

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle the default state is to trigger the change event manually after the registration of the handler so that the initial state of the element will be set

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input").change(function () {
        $("p").toggle(this.checked);
    }).change();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/58YsE/)

Comment: this is better, because it will work for example in FF on refresh. FF remembers already inputed data so it can be selected by default

Comment: I wouldn't be sure about cross broswer compatibility. use `$(this).prop('checked')` instead of `this.checked`

Comment: @MaciejPaprocki see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $('p').hide();
       $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
         $("p").toggle();
       });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rGyRW/1/

Answer (score -1):

please check ,its working,you need to add p{display:none}

Comment: also styles and mistakes are awful, unfortunately stackoverflow, doesn't allow me to edit it :(