# Rails Want to add fields to a form based on response of boolean entry

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm building a Rails 4 app and I want to add an if/then/else statement to a form. If the Boolean element is YES, then show X, else show Y. I seem to have run down a Coffee script rabbit hole and not sure I'm on the right track or not. I copied and pasted elements from another answer and have tried to use it it in a brand new rails app. It has not worked for me ever.

In my views ....views/invoices/_form.html.erb I have:

```
<label class="checkbox">
 <input id="user_holiday_ids_" name="user[holiday_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="2" />
 Valentine Day
</label>
<div style="display:none;">
    Whatever you need here<input type="text" id="foo" />
</div>
```

In my javascripts/invoices.js.coffee I have:

```
$(".checkbox").click ->
  $(this).next("div").toggle()
  return
```

In application.js I have (have not touched defaults...):

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

The checkbox is created, but the hidden form item does not toggle between hidden and show. I know it must be basic, but what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Here is the revised code that still does not work....

```
<div id="use_po">
    <%= f.label :use_po %><br>
    <%= f.check_box :use_po %>
</div>

 <div id="po_num_num">
    <%= f.label :po_number %><br>
 <%= collection_select(:invoice, :po_id, Po.all, :id, :po_num, prompt: true) %>
</div>


$("#use_po").change ->
  if $(this).is(":checked")
    $("#po_num_num").show()
  else
    $("#po_num_num").hide()
  return
```

Comment: you should read about javascript basics and this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642993/how-do-i-use-a-checkbox-to-toggle-another-element

Comment: Thank you. It still does not work for me. I'm sure it's basic, but I read the link and converted the jQuery to CoffeeScript. It's a form. When you hit the checkbox it should show or hide. I don't know how to make it any more straightforward. I've also tried creating a brand new rails app with nothing but this code, and it still does not work.