# Easy Toggleable Background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background-image

How do I create a check-box that toggles my website's background on and off? Basically, when I toggle a check-box I want it to locate an image and display it as a background. When I uncheck the check-box, I want it to disregard (or something that would achieve the same effect) the code that is setting the background.

*Note*: I have researched this topic on both Stackoverflow and Google, and while I found a few *helpful* articles, I did not find something that allowed me to achieve the effect I want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642993/how-do-i-use-a-checkbox-to-toggle-another-element    Instead of show hide toggle a class that has the background image property and one that doesn't have it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with jQuery `change` and `toggleclass` functions.

```js
$(function() {
    $('#checkbox').change(function(){
        $('body').toggleClass('toogle-bg'); 
    });
});
```

```css
.toogle-bg {
    background: url("http://goo.gl/Yu3rXz") 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input id="checkbox" type="checkbox"/> checkbox</label>
```